# Pass a whole object- Select tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my angular project,
using a select tag, how do I pass the whole accData object to my method ?

```html
<select 
    class="form-select form-select-sm" 
    aria-label=".form-select-sm example" 
    [disabled]="(appRoot.accountList | async)?.length === 1" 
    (change)="accountSelected(accData)"
>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let accData of (appRoot.accountList | async)" 
        [ngValue]="accData" 
        [selected]="accData.AccountName === selectedAccount"
    >
        {{ accData.AccountName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should need a `[(ngModel)]` and apply to the `select` element so that the variable can hold the selected object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can work with `[(ngModel)]`, two-binding to store the selected value.

```
selectedAcc: any = {};
```

```
<select 
    class="form-select form-select-sm" 
    aria-label=".form-select-sm example" 
    [disabled]="(appRoot.accountList | async)?.length === 1" 
    (change)="accountSelected(selectedAccount)"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedAcc"
>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let accData of (appRoot.accountList | async)" 
        [ngValue]="accData" 
        [selected]="accData.AccountName === selectedAccount"
    >
        {{ accData.AccountName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

With this, you don't need to have the `(change)` event to trigger the `accountSelected` function for binding the variable (unless in this function you require to perform additional logic). Also, I don't see any reason to use the `[selected]` attribute as if you implement the `[(ngModel)]`.

Thus, the simplified code should be:

```
<select 
    class="form-select form-select-sm" 
    aria-label=".form-select-sm example" 
    [disabled]="(appRoot.accountList | async)?.length === 1" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedAcc"
>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let accData of (appRoot.accountList | async)" 
        [ngValue]="accData"
    >
        {{ accData.AccountName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

---

Alternatively, if you are looking to maintain your existing structure, you can pass the `$event` to the `accountSelected` function.

```
<select 
    class="form-select form-select-sm" 
    aria-label=".form-select-sm example" 
    [disabled]="(appRoot.accountList | async)?.length === 1" 
    (change)="accountSelected($event)"
>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let accData of (appRoot.accountList | async)" 
        [ngValue]="accData" 
        [selected]="accData.AccountName === selectedAccount"
    >
        {{ accData.AccountName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

```
accountSelected(event: any) {
  let selectedAccount = event.target.value;

  this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount.AccountName;
}
```